# Sum up two vectors

Tags: java, vector

May I know how to sum two vectors in java?

```
public void CosineSimilarity(ArrayList<Integer> h,String a, Object[] array) throws Exception { 
           Vector value  = new Vector();
           double cos_sim=(cosine_similarity(vec1,vec2))*60/100;
           System.out.println(cos_sim); //I get [0.333] and [0.358]
           value.add(cos_sim);   
           CompareType(value,a,array);
}
```

**Here the CompareType function**

```
 public void CompareType(Vector value,String a,Object[] array ) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String k;
                double c = 0;
                String sql="Select Type from menu ";
                DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
                Connection  conn =db.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                Vector value1 = new Vector();
                while (rs.next()) 
                {
                k=rs.getString("Type");
                if(a.equals(k))
                {
                    c=10.0/100;
                    value1.add(c);
                    }
                else
                {
                    c=0;
                    value1.add(c);  
                }
                 }
                System.out.println(value1); // I get [0.0] and [0.1]
                Sum(value,value1);

                ps.close();
                rs.close();
                conn.close();

            }
```

What should I write in below function so the two values vectors can be added up and return two total values?

```
private void Sum(Vector value, Vector value1) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Comment: If you're using `java.util.Vector`, be aware that it is a badly named expandable list class. It is not an ideal object to represent a mathematical vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy thing with Java8 streaming API (this example code outputs `6.0` as the sum of `1.0+2.0+3.0`:

```
/** setup test data and call {@link #sum(Vector)} */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vector a = new Vector();
    Vector b = new Vector();

    a.add(1.0);
    a.add(2.0);
    b.add(3.0);

    System.out.println(sum(a, b));
}

/** Sum up all values of two vectors */
private static double sum(Vector value, Vector value1) {
    return sum(value) + sum(value1);
}

/** Sum up all values of one vector */
private static double sum(Vector value) {
    return

            // turn your vector into a stream
            value.stream()

            // make the stream of objects to a double stream (using generics would
            // make this easier)
            .mapToDouble(x -> (double) x)

            // use super fast internal sum method of java
            .sum();
}
```

Some ideas on how to make your code even better:

- Use **generics**. They will help you to avoid casts and the compiler will automatically show you bugs of your code.
- Name your variables and methods **meaningfully**. Use `sumA` and `sumB` instead of `sum` and `sum1`, etc.
- Use Java **coding conventions** (like using small case for method names). This will help other Java developers understand your code faster.
- Use **interfaces and superclasses** as variable types, return types and parameter types. This makes your code better reusable. Use `Collection` or `List` interfaces in your example.
- Use **java.util.ArrayList** in favor of `Vector`. (from official javadoc: "If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector.")

Comment: But I have 100 cases in my sql..this methods may not help

Comment: @seng Why may this method not help? Do you have performance concerns? Or do you have to sum 100 vectors instead of two?